# Is there a way to list all the authors who have published videos in a certain category and show them together, like a list?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Please help me with this website https://desarrollowebtotal.space/yoentrenoencasa/

I'm using goWatch theme from touchsize as parent theme.

What I need is this:

When I click on any of the categories listed on the home page, e.g. Yoga, the site will navigate to an archive with all the videos created in that taxonomy, it is not the behavior I want.

What I want is for that archive to return a list of authors who have published videos in that category and nested, as a list, show the videos associated with that author within that category.

Is it possible to do this?

```
  // This query brings the videos within the videos_categories taxonomy that match the current slug
    $term = get_queried_object();
      $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'video',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,

        'tax_query' => array( //(array) - use taxonomy parameters (available with Version 3.1).
            'relation' => 'AND', //(string) - Possible values are 'AND' or 'OR' and is the equivalent of running a JOIN for each taxonomy
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'videos_categories', //(string) - Taxonomy.
                'field' => 'slug', //(string) - Select taxonomy term by ('id' or 'slug')
                terms' => $term->slug, //(int/string/array) - Taxonomy term(s).
                include_children' => true, //(bool) - Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.
                'operator' => 'IN' //(string) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
              ),

            ),
    ) );
```

This is what I've done so far, I have no idea how to nest the video listings so that the parent is the author and the child the videos associated with that author

//UPDATE 1

```
     $argsA = array(
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC', 
        'number'        => null,
        'optioncount'   => false, 
        'exclude_admin' => true, 
        'show_fullname' => false,
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        'echo'          => true,
        // 'feed'          => [empty string], 
        // 'feed_image'    => [empty string],
        // 'feed_type'     => [empty string],
        'style'         => 'list',
        'html'          => true,
    );

    $authors = wp_list_authors($argsA);


     // This query brings the videos within the videos_categories taxonomy that match the current slug
    $term = get_queried_object();
```

HTML PART WHERE I LOOP THE RESULTS

```
  <div class="container airkit-archive-content">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if (!empty($authors)): ?>
                <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>

                    <?php  
                        $author_id = $author->ID;
                        $author_display_name = $author->name;

                        $query_args = array(
                          'author' => $author_id,
                          'post_type' => 'video',
                          'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'videos_categories',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => $term->slug,
                                'include_children' => true,
                                'operator' => 'IN'

                            ),
                          ),

                       );
                    ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?> 

            <?php endif ?>


        </div>
    </div>
```

The OUTPUT

- Cristian Entrenador
- j.b
- Jose Miguel
- Yonatan T.

What i need

- Trainer name

  - Videos he/she posted in the current category

UPDATE 2:

Doing as @Tokant requested/recommended i copy/pasted his snippet, it worked, it printed an author, i think it's because he's the only one who has posted videos

```php
      <div class="row">
            <?php $term = get_queried_object(); ?>

            <?php $authors_args = array(
                'echo'          => false,
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
            );




            $author_list = wp_list_authors($authors_args);




            if (!empty($author_list)):

                echo $author_list;

            foreach ($author_list as $author):
               $author_id = $author->ID;
               $author_display_name = $author->name;

               $query_args = array(
                  'author' => $author_id,

               );
               $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
               if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

               while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

               endwhile;
               wp_reset_postdata();
               endif;

            endforeach;
            endif; ?>


        </div>
```

OUPUTS THIS

- Jose Miguel

Comment: // , What is airkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning guys, thanks to Tokant I was able to find the solution in my own way.

What I did was put the layout together so that the hierarchy would be like this.

Author 
 - Videos posted in the current category.

This is the solution:

You have to install Buddypress plugin for 'orden' key to work, and add this script to functions.php of your child theme

```php
/*Función para ordenar los autores*/

add_action('show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields');

function extra_user_profile_fields($user)
{ ?>

    <?php if (current_user_can('administrator')) { ?>
        <h3><?php _e("Administrar Posiciones", "blank"); ?></h3>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="orden"><?php _e("Modificar Orden"); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="orden" id="orden" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('orden', $user->ID)); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                    <span class="description"><?php _e("Campo solo para administradores"); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }

add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');

function save_extra_user_profile_fields($user_id)
{
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'orden', $_POST['orden']);
}
```

- Loop for the authors:

```php
<?php
    // Theme's WP_Query arguments

    $airkit_video           = '';

    $figure_attributes      = array();

    $airkit_is_img          = airkit_single_option('img');
    $airkit_img_src         =wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($videos->ID));

    $airkit_video_type      = get_post_meta($videos->ID, 'video_type', true);
    $airkit_external_video  = get_post_meta($videos->ID, 'video_url', true);
    $airkit_embedded_video  = get_post_meta($videos->ID, 'video_embed', true);
    $airkit_uploaded_video  = get_post_meta($videos->ID, 'video_upload', true);

    //Arguments for users Query 
        $arg_user =  array(
            'role__in'             => ['author'],
            'post_type'            => 'video',
            'has_published_posts'  => ['video'],
            'fields'               => ['ID'],
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array('key' => 'orden', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '!='),
                    array('key' => 'orden', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        );

            //var_dump($arg_user);
            $yec_args = get_users($arg_user); //We obtain the list of all the users of the site to compare with the criteria of the query, it will look for in the author role, the users that have published entries in the custom post type video and it will avoid to bring the ones that do not have entries.

            $yec_user_id  = wp_list_pluck($yec_args, 'ID');
            //print_r($yec_user_id);

        ?>
?>
```

Then we loop through each author and output the html

```php
   <div class="container container-todo" style="transform: none; display: flex;">
            <div class="post-details-row current-reading" style="transform: none;">

        <?php
        // Loop & retrieve el ID authors ID

        foreach ($yec_user_id as $author_id): //main FOREACH
            // We get the ID of the current author who is returning the loop
            $curauth = get_userdata($author_id);
            //var_dump($curauth->user_nicename);

            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'video',
                'author' => $author_id,
                'groupby' => 'author',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'videos_categories',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => get_queried_object()->slug,
                    ),
                ),
                'meta_key' => 'airkit_views',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC'

            );

            //We return the videos and count them.

            $posts = get_posts($args);
            $number_post = count($posts);

            //var_dump($number_post);

            //if this author has posts, then include his name in the list otherwise don't


            if (isset($posts) && !empty($posts)) { // MAIN IF?>


                        <div class="row" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                            <div class="sidebar-right col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;">
                                <!-- Datos del autor -->
                                <div class="tszf-author-body">
                                    <div class="item col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="yec-user-image">
                                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_avatar_url($author_id)); ?>" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item col-xs-12">
                                            <span class="yec-authors"> <a href=" <?php echo get_option('siteurl') . '/members/' . $curauth->user_nicename . '/posts' ?>" class="post-link"> <?php echo "" . $curauth->first_name . " " . $curauth->last_name . ""; ?> </a></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tszf-user-name">

                                    <ul class="social"><?php echo airkit_var_sanitize($social_icons, 'the_kses'); ?></ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Fin de datos del autor -->


                                <!-- Aquí deben ir los vídeos de ese autor -->

                                <?php $count = 0;  ?>

                                <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
                                    <?php if ($count == "4") {
                                        // Si hay vídeos no imprimas más de 2 y salte del condicional
                                        break;
                                    } else{ ?>

                                        <!-- Este es el bloque iterable -->
                                        <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                            <article class="video type-video status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry has-lazy-placeholder airkit_view-article text-left below-image effect-always hidden-excerpt has-image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                                                <figure class="image-holder has-background-img lazy lazyloaded" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full') ?>); display: block;">

                                                    <a class="post-format-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">

                                                        <span class="post-type"><i class="icon-play-full"></i></span>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-link"></a>

                                                    <div class="overlay-effect ">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="overlay-link darken">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>

                                                </figure>


                                                <header class="entry-content-below">
                                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                                        <ul class="entry-categories">
                                                            <li class="term">
                                                                <?php $slug = get_queried_object()->slug;  ?>
                                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                                                                <!-- <a href="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>"><?php echo $slug; ?></a> -->
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>

                                                        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="name headline">
                                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $video->post_title; ?></a>

                                                            <div class="widget-meta">
                                                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                                                    <li class="red-comments">
                                                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) . '#comments' ?>">
                                                                            <i class="icon-comments"></i>
                                                                            <span class="comments-count">
                                                                                <?php echo airkit_var_sanitize($post->comment_count, 'the_kses') . ' '; ?>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </li>

                                                                    <li class="meta-views">
                                                                        <i class="icon-views-1"></i> <?php airkit_get_views($post->ID, true); ?>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </h2>
                                                    </div> <!-- Aquí termina el contenido de los vídeos -->
                                                </header>

                                            </article>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--Fin del bloque iterable -->


                                    <?php $count++; } //CIERRE DEL IF DEL COUNT ?> 
                                <?php } //CIERRE FOREACH DE POST    ?>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Flecha que nos lleva al perfil del autor -->
                            <a href=" <?php echo get_option('siteurl') . '/members/' . $curauth->user_nicename . '/posts' ?>" class="post-link">

                                <span style="font-size: 3em; color: rgba(60,185,207,1);">
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="margin-top:50px"></i>
                                </span>
                                <br />
                            </a>
                            <span style="color: rgba(60,185,207,1);"> (<?php echo $number_post; ?>) <i class="fas fa-video"></i> </span>
                            </div>




            <?php } // END of MAIN IF   ?>



        <?php endforeach; //END OF MAIN FOREACH ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a WP_Query for all authors. In the loop for each author you first get the author's ID and then create a WP_Query for the 'video' post type, just like you have already done but adding the authour's ID in the $args, like so:

```
$authors_args = array(
    'echo'          => false,
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
);
$authors = wp_list_authors($args);
if (!empty($authors)):
foreach ($authors as $author):
   $author_id = $author->ID;
   $author_display_name = $author->name;

   $query_args = array(
      'author' => $author_id,
      [your args]
   );
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   [output author name]
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      [output post/video]
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   endif;

endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Hey i tried this and it does not work entirely, i mean, it only lists the authors because of 
$authors = wp_list_authors($args) but it's like it ignores everything else so i cannot seem to list the videos, maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Take my exact code and replace [your args], [output author name] and [output post/video]

Comment: Thank you man, you were right, i posted the solution and gave you the credits for it